# UK spouse visa, traveling to the UK before application

Tags: visas

I am a British national. I would like to go to the UK to get a job so my wife can stay.

I don't want to be apart from my wife and child. We intend on traveling to the UK as a family, for 6 months. Then she would leave so I can apply for a spouse visa, once I have been working for 6 months. Is it possible to deny her entry, for this reason?

Has anyone done this?

Comment: *so my wife can stay*? What do you mean? Please [edit] your question, it is not very clear. What nationality is your wife? What *exactly* do you intend to do chronologically? What legal statutes/paperwork are involved in those steps?

Comment: While short stay visa questions are answered here, long stay questions are better asked on Expatriates StackExchange. They might be able to help you with the complete problem.

Comment: Hi thanks, sorry my post was very bland. I intend on traveling to the UK with my wife who is Japanese and my son who is a British citizen. I would like to go there to get a job earning over the threshold for applying for a spouse visa. I intend on taking my wife there for the 6 months she is entitled to stay then she will return to Japan for the remaining time whilst my employment reaches the 6 month mark before I can apply for a spouse visa. My question is what is the chance of her being denied entry to the UK if we tell them these are our plans, thanks again if you can answer this.

Comment: edit your question properly! couldn't understand what you're asking!!